# checking if LI has class applied to it and then detaching

Tags: jquery

I am a little stuck with some jQuery which is checking to see through a bunch of LI's to see if they have a specific class name applied - if they do have the specified class name applied - then they are ignored - all LI's that don't have that class name are detached from the HTML.

My code is:

```
var thisid = $(this).attr('id');

$("ul.bxslider li").not('.'+thisid).detach();
```

This works fine so long as the LU in bxslider has just one class name applied - e.g. class="test" - but if I add a 2nd class name to the LI e.g. class="test chicken" - then this code fails to work. Note I am passing a classname to the thisid variable to make this logic work, so with an LI that has class="test chicken" and when the thisid var is passed the string "chicken" it should not detach the LI with class="test chicken" but it does... what am I missing here?

Comment: Would hasClass help?
https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: Been thinking about that approach yes - but cant get the detach to work... my idea was if (!$('ul.bxslider li').hasClass('.'+thisid)) {
 $(this).detach();  
  }

Comment: detached element needs to be saved in some variable I guess `:/`

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dUQ4m/1/

Comment: @isherwood Yeah, I read it again and decided I actually agree with his interpretation of the question this time (I think, I'm still not 100%), which is why I deleted my comment.

Comment: OP, if the solution is unrelated to the question, please close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("ul.bxslider li").each(function(index)
{
    var thisElement = $(this);
    if (!thisElement.hasClass("test"))
    {
        thisElement.detach();
    }
});
```

Comment: This may well work, but it seems needlessly complex.

Comment: @isherwood yeah, but here we are: without elegant way of not-hasClass method for element which has more than one class.

Comment: thanks guys - this logic and my original logic should work - seems there is a bug in the CMS code adding the class names which is making these approaches appear not to work... annoying! thanks for your insigh!

Comment: @dubbs well, it is supposed that classes of element are splited by space in html...

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to generate the correct selector from your `id` string, so replace any spaces with a `.`:

```
var thisid = this.id;

$("ul.bxslider li").not('.' + thisid.replace(/ /g, '.')).detach();
```